# How to specify offset by time instead of bars? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Some of my rules (to detect something) gives false alarms for an hour after Market Open (or simply just not defined well enough anyways, ha-ha). Since I can locate the moment of Market Open, I can address bars relatively to it which is kinda cool. Is there a way to specify offset by time to make it undependent to (sub-hour) timeframe?

For example in my code, `MarketOpen` rule is `true` if the current the moment of Market Open is still in the current bar (so it addresses the bar of `MarketOpen` in any timeframe). In 1H timeframe, it would be simple: `not(MarketOpen)` would exclude the first hour, but it should work in sub-hour timeframes, too.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit your question ? Can you show us how your code specify offset by bars, so we can propose you how to do the same with time ?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help this long after. :) It was long ago and I found a workaround in that specific case. How to define this Boolean variable: THING_HappenedTwoHoursAgoOrMore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trade only in specific hours, you can use a `session`:

```
session = input.session("1100-2000")
inSession = not na(time(timeframe.period, session))

long = inSession and yourCondition
```

In any case, if you want to get the time of 1 hour after the market is open, you can use this:

```
newDay = ta.change(time("D"))
var float oneHourAfterMarketOpen = na

if newDay
    oneHourAfterMarketOpen := time + (60 * 60 * 1000)

canTrade = time > oneHourAfterMarketOpen

bgcolor(canTrade?color.green:color.red)
```